# How to create a sql trigger to set a table column equal to a value after insert?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, count, triggers

new to oracle and sql but trying to learn triggers. I think I'm having some syntax errors here, but let me explain what I am trying to do.

I have two tables: 1. **group_membership** with the columns

```
user_internal_id | group_internal_id (FK) | joined_time
```

and 2. **group_details** with the columns

```
group_internal_id (PK) | group_name | group_owner | created_time | movie_cnt | member_cnt|
```

(PK and FK stand for Primary Key and Foreign Key that relates to that Primary Key respectively.)

**What I want to do:**

After a new row is inserted into the **group_membership** table, I want to
update the value of *member_cnt* in the **group_details** table with the amount of times a particular *group_internal_id* appears in the **group_membership** table.

--

Now, my DBA for the app we are working on has created a trigger that simply updates the *member_cnt* of a particular group by reading the *group_internal_id* of the row inserted to **group_membership**, then adding 1 to the member_cnt. Which works better probably, but I want to figure out how come my trigger is having errors. Here is the code below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER set_group_size
AFTER INSERT ON group_membership
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE g_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(group_internal_id) 
    INTO g_count 
    FROM group_membership
    GROUP BY group_internal_id;
    
    UPDATE group_details
    SET member_cnt = g_count
    WHERE group_details.group_internal_id = group_membership.group_internal_id;
END;
```

The errors I'm receiving are:

```
Error(7,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(9,45): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "GROUP_MEMBERSHIP"."GROUP_INTERNAL_ID": invalid identifier
```

I came here because my efforts have bene futile in troubleshooting. Hope to hear some feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @GMB that your design is fundamentally flawed, but if you insist on keeping a running count there is a easy solution to mutating they point out. The entire process is predicated on maintaining the count in group_details.member_count column. Therefore since that column has the previous count you do not need to count them - so eliminate the select. Your trigger becomes:

```
create or replace trigger set_group_size
    after insert on group_membership
    for each row
begin
    update group_details
       set member_cnt = member_cnt + 1
    where group_details.group_internal_id = :new.group_internal_id;
end;
```

Of course then you need to handle group_membership Deletes and Updates of group_internal_id. Also, what happens when 2 users process the same group_membership simultaneously?  
 Maintaining a running total for a *derivable column* is just not worth the effort. Best option just create the view as GMB suggested.

Comment: Yes, my DBA has created a trigger similar to this. On delete another trigger will run and, it will subtract 1 from the members_cnt column. I am new to oracle and sql so I was curious in seeing if my method was effective at all. Regardless though, given time complexity, we won't be using my method lol. Does a view

Answer (score 3):

The immeidate issue with your code is the `update` query of your trigger:

```
UPDATE group_details
SET member_cnt = g_count
WHERE group_details.group_internal_id = group_membership.group_internal_id;
```

`group_membership` is not defined in that scope. To refer to the value on the rows that is being inserted, use pseudo-table `:new` instead.

```
WHERE group_details.group_internal_id = :new.group_internal_id;
```

Another problem is the `select` query, that might return multiple rows. It would need a `where` clause that filters on the newly inserted `group_internal_id`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO g_count 
FROM group_membership
WHERE group_internal_id = :new.group_internal_id;
```

---

**But these obvious fixes are not sufficient**. Oracle won't let you `select` from the table that the trigger fired upon. On execution, you would meet error:

```
ORA-04091: table GROUP_MEMBERSHIP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

There is no easy way around this. Let me suggest that this whole design is broken; the count of members per group is *derived information*, that can easily be computed on the fly whenever needed. Instead of trying to store it, you could, for example, use a view:

```
create view view_group_details as
select group_internal_id, group_name, 
    (
        select count(*) 
        from group_membership gm 
        where gm.group_internal_id = gd.group_internal_id
    ) member_cnt
from group_details gd
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My DBA explained to me that my method is not effective regardless, because selecting a count is slower than simply updating the member_cnt of a specific group by 1 everytime a row is inserted to group_membership.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: possibly, but then your DBA should suggest a technically viable way to maintain the information. My answer explained that using a trigger for this is just not possible, given your current layout.

Comment: For this case, the information needs to be stored because members_cnt is a column in another table. His method is to update the members_cnt column by 1, by reading the group_id of a new group upon insert to group_membership, and adding 1 to their current count. Now that I understand that my method is not possible, I understand that a simpler method is needed for the trigger to run. I was just curious if my method could work in anyway or not.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi: I understand. It gets complicated if the base information is updated though (that is, the group of a user is changed).

Comment: In this case, a user can be a member of multiple groups, but can exist in each group only once. There is a separate user table I did not include where a user has a unique ID.